# Implementing the Double Ratchet algorithm

Tags: cryptography, hkdf, signal-protocol

I'm trying to implement from scratch the Double Ratchet algorithm using [this](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/doubleratchet/) as my guide, however I am not an expert of crypto stuff, thus some things are quite unclear:

1. The guide refers to a "root key" `RK`, and an output of a `DH` as parameters to the function `KDF_RK(rk, dh_out)`, but I need to know what is this root key and how it must be initialized the first time.
2. I see that `KDF_RK(rk, dh_out)`  and `KDF_CK(ck)` are based on the HKDF cryptographic function: can someone make a drawing in order to make me better understand how those functions work? It is enough a simulation of a typical execution between Alice and Bob in a pseudo code fashion.

Thank you

Comment: You really should ask this on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).